# How to interpolate between numerial data table values in Dart ( actually in any language )

Tags: function, dart, interpolation

I have a simple data table with x and y values, something like this:

```
x     y
-10  -0.505
-9   -0.422
-8   -0.335
-7   -0.243
-6   -0.148
-5   -0.051
-4    0.046
-3    0.144
-2    0.242
-1    0.34
0     0.539
1     0.658
2     0.773
3     0.716
4     0.8
5     0.88
6     0.952
7     1.016
8     1.071
9     1.116
10    1.15
```

The x step size as well as the min and max values might be different.

I am looking for a built-in functionality to interpolate between these values.
So I need a function which takes the x values and returns the corresponding y value. When there is no exact match, I need the function to linearly interpolate between the two closest values.

Of course I could write my own function but I feel like there might be an easy solution, maybe even built-in in Dart.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks & cheers

Tobi

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SplayTreeMap<double, double> to store your values. The key represents the range to search within.Then use an interpolation function as shown below:

```
var kEfficiencyMotorsFullLoad = SplayTreeMap<double, double>.from({
    0.75: .825,
    1.1: .841,
    1.5: .853,
    2.2: .867,
    3.0: .877,
    4.0: .886,
    5.5: .896,
    7.5: .904,
    11.0: .914,
    15.0: .921,
    18.5: .926,
    22.0: .930,
    30.0: .936,
  });


double linearInterpolate(double target, SplayTreeMap<double, double> values) {
  if (values.containsKey(target)) return values[target]!;

  double? xa = values.lastKeyBefore(target);
  double? xb = values.firstKeyAfter(target);

  //very small key
  if (xa != null && xb == null) return values[xa]!;
  //very large key
  if (xa == null && xb != null) return values[xb]!;
  //strange error
  if (xa == null && xb == null)
    throw Exception(
        "number was not found in the SplayTreeMap, check if it is not empty");

  double ya = values[xa] ?? 0;
  double yb = values[xb] ?? 0;

  return ya + ((yb - ya) * ((target - xa!) / (xb! - xa)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some package on pub.dev that does it already, but I'd use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) and its [`lastKeyBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/lastKeyBefore.html) and [`firstKeyAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap/firstKeyAfter.html) methods to find the surrounding points and then interpolate between them.  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:collection' show SplayTreeMap;
import 'dart:math' show Point;

/// Returns the y-coordinate for the specified x-coordinate on the line defined
/// by two given points.
double _interpolate(Point<double> p0, Point<double> p1, double x) {
  // y - y0 = m * (x - x0)
  var m = (p1.y - p0.y) / (p1.x - p0.x);
  return m * (x - p0.x) + p0.y;
}

class InterpolatingMap {
  final SplayTreeMap<double, double> _data;

  InterpolatingMap(Map<double, double> data)
      : _data = SplayTreeMap<double, double>.of(data);

  double operator [](double x) {
    var value = _data[x];
    if (value != null) {
      return value;
    }
    
    if (_data.isEmpty) {
      throw StateError('InterpolatingMap is empty');
    }

    double? lower = _data.lastKeyBefore(x);
    double? upper = _data.firstKeyAfter(x);
    assert(lower != null || upper != null);

    double x0;
    double x1;
    if (lower == null) {
      // `x` is to the left of the left-most data point.  Extrapolate from the
      // first two entries.
      x0 = upper!;
      x1 = _data.firstKeyAfter(upper) ?? x0;
    } else if (upper == null) {
      // `x` is to the right of the right-most data point.  Extrapolate from the
      // last two entries.
      x1 = lower;
      x0 = _data.lastKeyBefore(lower) ?? x1;
    } else {
      x0 = lower;
      x1 = upper;
    }

    return _interpolate(
      Point<double>(x0, _data[x0]!),
      Point<double>(x1, _data[x1]!),
      x,
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  var interpolatingMap = InterpolatingMap({
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 1,
  });

  print(interpolatingMap[-1]);   // Prints: 0
  print(interpolatingMap[0]);    // Prints: 1
  print(interpolatingMap[0.25]); // Prints: 1.25
  print(interpolatingMap[0.5]);  // Prints: 1.5
  print(interpolatingMap[0.75]); // Prints: 1.75
  print(interpolatingMap[1]);    // Prints: 2
  print(interpolatingMap[1.5]);  // Prints: 1.5
  print(interpolatingMap[3]);    // Prints: 0
}
```

Note that `InterpolatingMap` in the above implementation is a bit of a misnomer since it also will extrapolate values outside the data range. (It should be trivial to make it throw an exception if you want to disable extrapolation, however.) It also doesn't implement the `Map` interface (which is left as an exercise for readers who care about that).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use binary search to find the matching range, then interpolate from that.
You can use the [`lowerBound`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListExtensions/lowerBound.html) method from `package:collection` to find the largest element less then or equal to the element you search for.

Something like:

```dart
import"package:collection/collection.dart";
double interpolate(List<num> keyPoints, List<num> values, num x) {
  if (keyPoints.length < 2) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(keyPoints, "keyPoints", 
        "Needs at least two points to interpolate");
  }
  if (keyPoints.length != values.length) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(values, "values", 
        "Must have the same number of elements as the key points");
  }
  var p = keyPoints.lowerBound(x);
  if (p > keyPoints.length - 2) p = keyPoints.length - 2;
  var startPosition = keyPoints[p];
  var endPosition = keyPoints[p + 1];
  var startValue = values[p];
  var endValue = values[p + 1];
  return (x - startPosition) / (endPosition - startPosition) * (endValue - startValue);
}
```

This will interpolate the value when `x` is between two key-points, and extrapolate the first or last range if the `x` value is outside the key-point range.